# Parallel Coordinates D3.js -- brushing not selecting tuples

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, parallel-coordinates

The brushing on my D3.js parallel coordinates stopped working when I switched from loading the json data from a file to preloading it with jquery. I did this so that I could apply some filters to the data prior to loading it into the parallel coordinates.

The parallel coordinates are still rendering, but I am not unable to use brushing.  When I do, it returns a blank result (nothing is selected).

I create the parallel coordinates here:

```
                var pc = d3.parcoords({
                    dimensionTitles: {
                        nplay_video: "video plays",
                        final_cc_cname_DI: "country",
                        LoE_DI: "education level",
                        nevents: "# of events",
                        nforum_posts: "# of forums posts",
                        nchapters: "# of chapters",
                        ndays_act: "# days active"
                    }
                })('#example')
```

And load the data

```
                function refreshCoordinates(data){
                    // generate the parallel-coordinates
                    pc.data(data)
                        .ticks(4)
                        .mode("queue")
                        .color(color)
                        .composite("darker")
                        .alpha(0.15)
                        .render()
                        .dimensions(['LoE_DI','ndays_act', 'nchapters', 'nplay_video', 'nevents', 'nforum_posts', 'grade', 'certified'])
                        .createAxes()
                        .brushMode("1D-axes")
                        .interactive()
                        .reorderable();
                }
```

The data is loaded, filtered using jquery, and updated when the user selects different attributes.  Everything but the brushing seems to be working fine. I'm pretty new to D3.js so hopefully I'm just making a silly mistake. Thanks!

EDIT: If I load from a json file, then the brushing works.  When I update the data I call a function to...

```
pc.data(data).render().updateAxes();
```

This is when the parallel coordinates stop being able to be brushed.